# Closing the Popup Window in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, popupwindow, keyevent

IN My App i have shown a popup window at the sametime keybaord is visible on screen when
i'm pressing the back button first keyboard is gone and after pressing the back button again
poup window get dismissed. I want to close the popup window first.

I have tried to use KeyEvent_BACK but it not working.

please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

```
mPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
mPopUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
// display the popup in the center
mPopUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

It works like a champ

Comment: Works like a charm ! Confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

use the dismiss method to hide the popup

Answer (score 0):

```
mPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

Here, the new BitmapDrawable() is deprecated.
Hence, i did it like this
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent));
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

And It Works !